Gaining administrator privileges from Function PowerShell
1. GetAdmin from function inside Script
function test {
    GetAdmin
    
    if ( $(fltmc).count -eq 3) { 'Not Admin' } else { 'Admin' }
    write-host "`'$PSCommandPath`'"
    pause; exit 0
}

function GetAdmin {
   if ( $(fltmc).count -eq 3) {
       $arg = "-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass", "-File `"$PSCommandPath`""
        Start -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -ArgumentList $arg; exit 0
    }
}
test 

When GetAdmin function inside script (in the same file), there is no problem. Everything is OK.

2. GetAdmin from function outside Script
I tried to make GetAdmin function calledable from script above, and place it in $env:PSModulePath.
So that I can calling it whenever I need, without including it in every scripts that needs admin elevate.
function GetAdmin {
   if ( $(fltmc).count -eq 3) {
       $arg = "-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass", "-File `"$PSCommandPath`""
        Start -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -ArgumentList $arg; exit 0
    }
}

And making sure the function was loaded
gcm 'GetAdmin'
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        GetAdmin                                           0.0.1      bill

After that..., I tried to call the function from a .ps1 file
# test.ps1
GetAdmin

if ( $(fltmc).count -eq 3) { 'Not Admin' } else { 'Admin' }
write-host "`'$PSCommandPath`'"
pause; exit 0 

But The script always auto closes. can't go back to test.ps1
Perhaps someone can help me.
making GetAdmin Function calledable.
I mean Get Admin elevate from outside /other script.
Not from inside script

All programs are by default started in non-administrator mode, even if
the current account is that of an administrator.
If you are running the PowerShell script from an administrator account,
but have not used "Run as Administrator", the following code will
relaunch itself again in Administrator mode:
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
 $myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
 $myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)
  
 # Get the security principal for the Administrator role
 $adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
  
 # Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
 if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
    {
    # We are running "as Administrator" - so change the title and background color to indicate this
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
    clear-host
    }
 else
    {
    # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator
    
    # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
    $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";
    
    # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
    $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;
    
    # Indicate that the process should be elevated
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";
    
    # Start the new process
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);
    
    # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
    exit
    }
  
 # Run your code that needs to be elevated here
 Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue..."
 $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

Source :
A self elevating PowerShell script.

Thanks. It's seem still from inside. How about from outside ?

You would need to run elevated to start with,  using start-process with the runas parameter.

This script getting error when ps1 name contains space. When test.ps1 it's OK, when test .ps1 or te st.ps1 error.

It's the same in CMD - you need to quote a name with blanks (" or ').

I've finished creating the script.
With this script, I simply input the SUDO command every time I need Adminstartor privileges
<#
Place this Script in $Env:PSModulePath with the requirements
Make sure the script was loaded (Get-Command SUDO)
Works both from commandline and Script

Usage:
SUDO
SUDO <.Ps1 File>

Example: from Script
sudo
sudo $PSCommandPath
    
Example: from commandline
sudo
sudo "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.ps1"
#>

function SUDO {
    Param()
    # Error handling when the file is not .ps1 or not exist
    if ( $Args.Count -eq 1 -and $Args.EndsWith('.ps1') -and (Test-Path $Args) ) {
        $PS1File   = $Args
        $PS1Path   = (Get-ChildItem $PS1File).DirectoryName
    }
    
    # Alwasy run in WT.exe | $False to disable
    $PreferWT  = $True
    # Alwasy prefer PWSH.exe | $False to disable
    $PreferPS7 = $True
    $isWT      = where.exe wt.exe 2>$null
    $isPS7     = (Host).Version.Major -eq 7
    $isAdmin   = (fltmc).Count -ne 3
    
    if ( $isPS7 -and $PreferPS7 ) {
        $PS = 'pwsh.exe';       $prof = 'PowerShell'
    } else {
        $PS = 'powershell.exe'; $prof = 'Windows PowerShell'
    }

    if ( !$isAdmin ) {
        if ( $isWT -and $PreferWT ) {
            if ( $PS1File ) {
                $AL = "-d `"$PS1Path`" -p `"$prof`"", "cmd /c $PS -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PS1File`""
            } else {
                $AL = "-p `"$prof`""
            }
            Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath "wt.exe" -ArgumentList $AL
            taskkill.exe /f /im $PID
        } else {
            if ( $PS1File ) {
                $AL = "-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass", "-File `"$PS1File`""
                Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath $PS -ArgumentList $AL
            } else {
                Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath $PS
            }
        }
        exit 0
    }
}

